# Method Swizzling Implementation not taking place

Tags: ios, objective-c, swizzling

I am trying to learn the concept of swizzling.

Even though I have added `method_exchangeImplementations`, still the methods are not being swizzled. Any idea as to where I am going wrong?

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface POCViewController ()

- (void)addSwizzle;
- (void)originalMethod;
- (void)swizzledMethod;

@end

@implementation POCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Add swizzle
    [self addSwizzle];

    //Call the original method
    [self originalMethod];
}

- (void)addSwizzle
{
    Method original, swizz;

    original = class_getClassMethod([self class], @selector(originalMethod));
    swizz = class_getClassMethod([self class], @selector(swizzledMethod));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizz);
}

- (void)originalMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Inside original method");
}

- (void)swizzledMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Inside swizzled method");
    [self swizzledMethod];
}
```

Comment: Don't use swizzling outside of unit tests and debugging.  It is both against App Store policy and it'll lead to horribly fragile code.

Comment: Swizzling isn't against App Store policy - was it before when this comment was made? It can certainly lead to fragile code, but it also allows neat things like Aspect oriented code (for example: https://github.com/steipete/Aspects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `class_getClassMethod` to get implementations of instance methods, you should use `class_getInstanceMethod` instead.

`method_exchangeImplementations` is still used the same way

Comment: Ah!!Cant believe I did not notice that.
Thanks a lot Wattson.

Comment: no worries. one way to debug things like this is that original and swizz would have been NULL, usually a good sign something has gone wrong

Comment: yep should have printed the values.
hey, you have any clue about forward invocation as well?

Comment: as in NSProxy? i haven't used it much, do you mean when combined with swizzling, or as an alternative?

Comment: Na, as in forwardinvocation & methodForSignature methods.

Nonetheless thanks for the help mate!!

Comment: i don't know too much about that but [mike ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html) is usually a good source for in-depth topics